# azure pipelines for static website hosted on azure storage blob

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have a static website stored on an azure storage blob with a web container.
I also create two pipelines one for build and one for release and there are triggered for any git push.

However, even the pipelines do not return any error, the files from my static website aren't updated.

With the azure static web apps, the website works fine.

The build pipeline is:

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

And the release pipeline is :

[image][image]
Do you have any hints about how should I fix this issue?

The release pipeline logs is:

```
2020-09-04T10:20:02.6569221Z ##[section]Starting: Initialize job
2020-09-04T10:20:02.6571745Z Agent name: 'Hosted Agent'
2020-09-04T10:20:02.6572142Z Agent machine name: 'WIN-O9T7OURK3J6'
2020-09-04T10:20:02.6572400Z Current agent version: '2.174.1'
2020-09-04T10:20:02.6596779Z Current image version: '20200827.1'
2020-09-04T10:20:02.6604603Z Agent running as: 'VssAdministrator'
2020-09-04T10:20:02.6614963Z Prepare release directory.
2020-09-04T10:20:02.6623759Z ReleaseId=4, TeamProjectId=8a218a65-218f-4a0b-a776-ac7b99e00a44, ReleaseDefinitionName=New release pipeline
2020-09-04T10:20:02.6749896Z Release folder: D:\a\r1\a
2020-09-04T10:20:02.6899665Z Environment variables available are below.  Note that these environment variables can be referred to in the task (in the ReleaseDefinition) by replacing "_" with "." e.g. AGENT_NAME environment variable can be referenced using Agent.Name in the ReleaseDefinition: 
                [AGENT_DISABLELOGPLUGIN_TESTFILEPUBLISHERPLUGIN] --> [true]
                [AGENT_DISABLELOGPLUGIN_TESTRESULTLOGPLUGIN] --> [true]
                [AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY] --> [C:\agents\2.174.1]
                [AGENT_ID] --> [8]
                [AGENT_JOBNAME] --> [Agent job]
                [AGENT_MACHINENAME] --> [WIN-O9T7OURK3J6]
                [AGENT_NAME] --> [Hosted Agent]
                [AGENT_OS] --> [Windows_NT]
                [AGENT_OSARCHITECTURE] --> [X64]
                [AGENT_RELEASEDIRECTORY] --> [D:\a\r1\a]
                [AGENT_RETAINDEFAULTENCODING] --> [false]
                [AGENT_ROOTDIRECTORY] --> [D:\a]
                [AGENT_SERVEROMDIRECTORY] --> [C:\agents\2.174.1\externals\vstsom]
                [AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY] --> [D:\a\_temp]
                [AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY] --> [C:/hostedtoolcache/windows]
                [AGENT_VERSION] --> [2.174.1]
                [AGENT_WORKFOLDER] --> [D:\a]
                [AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT] --> [VSTS_24daeef5-3f0a-4531-b444-5497df41caae_Release__4_4_1]
                [BUILD_BUILDID] --> [4]
                [BUILD_BUILDNUMBER] --> [20200904.4]
                [BUILD_BUILDURI] --> [vstfs:///Build/Build/4]
                [BUILD_DEFINITIONID] --> [1]
                [BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME] --> [aurelian84.acudoclarisa]
                [BUILD_PROJECTID] --> [8a218a65-218f-4a0b-a776-ac7b99e00a44]
                [BUILD_PROJECTNAME] --> [acudoclarisa]
                [BUILD_REPOSITORY_ID] --> [aurelian84/acudoclarisa]
                [BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME] --> [aurelian84/acudoclarisa]
                [BUILD_REPOSITORY_PROVIDER] --> [GitHub]
                [BUILD_REQUESTEDFOR] --> [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS]
                [BUILD_REQUESTEDFORID] --> [00000002-0000-8888-8000-000000000000]
                [BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH] --> [refs/heads/master]
                [BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME] --> [master]
                [BUILD_SOURCEVERSION] --> [b260e54d894d9f6a1f0b709f33a8a4fef35251de]
                [BUILD_TYPE] --> [Build]
                [GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT] --> [0]
                [MSDEPLOY_HTTP_USER_AGENT] --> [VSTS_24daeef5-3f0a-4531-b444-5497df41caae_Release__4_4_1]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DROP_BUILDID] --> [4]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DROP_BUILDNUMBER] --> [20200904.4]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DROP_BUILDURI] --> [vstfs:///Build/Build/4]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DROP_DEFINITIONID] --> [1]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DROP_DEFINITIONNAME] --> [aurelian84.acudoclarisa]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DROP_PROJECTID] --> [8a218a65-218f-4a0b-a776-ac7b99e00a44]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DROP_PROJECTNAME] --> [acudoclarisa]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DROP_REPOSITORY_ID] --> [aurelian84/acudoclarisa]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DROP_REPOSITORY_NAME] --> [aurelian84/acudoclarisa]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DROP_REPOSITORY_PROVIDER] --> [GitHub]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DROP_REQUESTEDFOR] --> [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DROP_REQUESTEDFORID] --> [00000002-0000-8888-8000-000000000000]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DROP_SOURCEBRANCH] --> [refs/heads/master]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DROP_SOURCEBRANCHNAME] --> [master]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DROP_SOURCEVERSION] --> [b260e54d894d9f6a1f0b709f33a8a4fef35251de]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DROP_TYPE] --> [Build]
                [RELEASE_ATTEMPTNUMBER] --> [1]
                [RELEASE_DEFINITIONENVIRONMENTID] --> [1]
                [RELEASE_DEFINITIONID] --> [1]
                [RELEASE_DEFINITIONNAME] --> [New release pipeline]
                [RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_REQUESTEDFOR] --> [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS]
                [RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_REQUESTEDFOREMAIL] --> []
                [RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_REQUESTEDFORID] --> [00000002-0000-8888-8000-000000000000]
                [RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_STARTTIME] --> [2020-09-04 10:19:40Z]
                [RELEASE_DEPLOYMENTID] --> [4]
                [RELEASE_DEPLOYPHASEID] --> [4]
                [RELEASE_ENVIRONMENTID] --> [4]
                [RELEASE_ENVIRONMENTNAME] --> [toAzure]
                [RELEASE_ENVIRONMENTS_TOAZURE_STATUS] --> [InProgress]
                [RELEASE_ENVIRONMENTURI] --> [vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Environment/4]
                [RELEASE_PRIMARYARTIFACTSOURCEALIAS] --> [drop]
                [RELEASE_REASON] --> [ContinuousIntegration]
                [RELEASE_RELEASEDESCRIPTION] --> [Triggered by aurelian84.acudoclarisa 20200904.4.]
                [RELEASE_RELEASEID] --> [4]
                [RELEASE_RELEASENAME] --> [Release-4]
                [RELEASE_RELEASEURI] --> [vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Release/4]
                [RELEASE_RELEASEWEBURL] --> [https://dev.azure.com/aurelianrosca/8a218a65-218f-4a0b-a776-ac7b99e00a44/_release?releaseId=4&_a=release-summary]
                [RELEASE_REQUESTEDFOR] --> [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS]
                [RELEASE_REQUESTEDFOREMAIL] --> []
                [RELEASE_REQUESTEDFORID] --> [00000002-0000-8888-8000-000000000000]
                [RELEASE_SKIPARTIFACTSDOWNLOAD] --> [False]
                [RELEASE_TRIGGERINGARTIFACT_ALIAS] --> [drop]
                [REQUESTEDFORID] --> [00000002-0000-8888-8000-000000000000]
                [SYSTEM] --> [release]
                [SYSTEM_ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY] --> [D:\a\r1\a]
                [SYSTEM_COLLECTIONID] --> [24daeef5-3f0a-4531-b444-5497df41caae]
                [SYSTEM_COLLECTIONURI] --> [https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/aurelianrosca/]
                [SYSTEM_CULTURE] --> [en-US]
                [SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY] --> [D:\a\r1\a]
                [SYSTEM_DEFINITIONID] --> [1]
                [SYSTEM_DEFINITIONNAME] --> [New release pipeline]
                [SYSTEM_ENABLEACCESSTOKEN] --> [False]
                [SYSTEM_HOSTTYPE] --> [release]
                [SYSTEM_JOBATTEMPT] --> [1]
                [SYSTEM_JOBDISPLAYNAME] --> [Agent job]
                [SYSTEM_JOBID] --> [acac96fb-4295-5d89-efc2-a34af29daef3]
                [SYSTEM_JOBIDENTIFIER] --> [Stage_8a218a65218f4a0ba776ac7b99e00a44_1_1.Phase_1.__default]
                [SYSTEM_JOBNAME] --> [__default]
                [SYSTEM_JOBPARALLELISMTAG] --> [Private]
                [SYSTEM_JOBPOSITIONINPHASE] --> [1]
                [SYSTEM_JOBTIMEOUT] --> [0]
                [SYSTEM_PHASEATTEMPT] --> [1]
                [SYSTEM_PHASEDISPLAYNAME] --> [Agent job]
                [SYSTEM_PHASEID] --> [4bad69ec-5c1e-55e1-09ea-2681215800be]
                [SYSTEM_PHASENAME] --> [Phase_1]
                [SYSTEM_PIPELINESTARTTIME] --> [2020-09-04 10:19:58+00:00]
                [SYSTEM_PLANID] --> [bd50236b-b701-4b74-b700-1281e6e1e57a]
                [SYSTEM_SERVERTYPE] --> [Hosted]
                [SYSTEM_STAGEATTEMPT] --> [1]
                [SYSTEM_STAGEDISPLAYNAME] --> [toAzure]
                [SYSTEM_STAGEID] --> [c4c93af3-ce6a-5174-31b1-90fefd4e8937]
                [SYSTEM_STAGENAME] --> [Stage_8a218a65218f4a0ba776ac7b99e00a44_1_1]
                [SYSTEM_TASKDEFINITIONSURI] --> [https://dev.azure.com/aurelianrosca/]
                [SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI] --> [https://dev.azure.com/aurelianrosca/]
                [SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI] --> [https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/aurelianrosca/]
                [SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT] --> [acudoclarisa]
                [SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID] --> [8a218a65-218f-4a0b-a776-ac7b99e00a44]
                [SYSTEM_TIMELINEID] --> [bd50236b-b701-4b74-b700-1281e6e1e57a]
                [SYSTEM_TOTALJOBSINPHASE] --> [1]
                [SYSTEM_WORKFOLDER] --> [D:\a]
2020-09-04T10:20:03.0094507Z Creating artifacts directory: D:\a\r1\a
2020-09-04T10:20:03.0434758Z Created artifacts directory: D:\a\r1\a
2020-09-04T10:20:03.0513258Z Download all required tasks.
2020-09-04T10:20:03.0519915Z Checking job knob settings.
2020-09-04T10:20:03.0530087Z    Knob: AgentToolsDirectory = C:/hostedtoolcache/windows Source: ${AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY} 
2020-09-04T10:20:03.0531393Z    Knob: AgentPerflog = C:\agents\perflog Source: ${VSTS_AGENT_PERFLOG} 
2020-09-04T10:20:03.0533320Z Finished checking job knob settings.
2020-09-04T10:20:03.0758557Z Start tracking orphan processes.
2020-09-04T10:20:03.0845073Z ##[section]Finishing: Initialize job

2020-09-04T10:20:03.1184370Z ##[section]Starting: Finalize Job
2020-09-04T10:20:03.1268363Z Cleaning up task key
2020-09-04T10:20:03.1271152Z Start cleaning up orphan processes.
2020-09-04T10:20:03.1366622Z ##[section]Finishing: Finalize Job
```

And the buil pipeline log is:

```
2020-09-04T10:08:48.8079982Z ##[section]Starting: Job
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1221493Z ##[section]Starting: Initialize job
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1222911Z Agent name: 'Hosted Agent'
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1223535Z Agent machine name: 'fv-az89'
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1223836Z Current agent version: '2.174.1'
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1266730Z ##[group]Operating System
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1267036Z Ubuntu
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1267255Z 18.04.5
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1267446Z LTS
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1267668Z ##[endgroup]
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1267909Z ##[group]Virtual Environment
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1268198Z Environment: ubuntu-18.04
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1268456Z Version: 20200825.1
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1268858Z Included Software: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/ubuntu18/20200825.1/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1269324Z ##[endgroup]
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1270392Z Current image version: '20200825.1'
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1275298Z Agent running as: 'vsts'
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1322729Z Prepare build directory.
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1641593Z Set build variables.
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1677809Z Download all required tasks.
2020-09-04T10:08:49.1803413Z Downloading task: CmdLine (2.164.2)
2020-09-04T10:08:51.3084701Z Checking job knob settings.
2020-09-04T10:08:51.3095779Z    Knob: AgentToolsDirectory = /opt/hostedtoolcache Source: ${AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY} 
2020-09-04T10:08:51.3097416Z    Knob: AgentPerflog = /home/vsts/perflog Source: ${VSTS_AGENT_PERFLOG} 
2020-09-04T10:08:51.3098318Z Finished checking job knob settings.
2020-09-04T10:08:51.3409521Z Start tracking orphan processes.
2020-09-04T10:08:51.3599665Z ##[section]Finishing: Initialize job
2020-09-04T10:08:51.3958789Z ##[section]Starting: Checkout aurelian84/acudoclarisa@master to s
2020-09-04T10:08:51.4184611Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-04T10:08:51.4185298Z Task         : Get sources
2020-09-04T10:08:51.4185880Z Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
2020-09-04T10:08:51.4186271Z Version      : 1.0.0
2020-09-04T10:08:51.4186734Z Author       : Microsoft
2020-09-04T10:08:51.4187401Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
2020-09-04T10:08:51.4187851Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-04T10:08:52.3231348Z Syncing repository: aurelian84/acudoclarisa (GitHub)
2020-09-04T10:08:52.3234224Z ##[command]git version
2020-09-04T10:08:52.3237544Z git version 2.28.0
2020-09-04T10:08:52.3238571Z ##[command]git lfs version
2020-09-04T10:08:52.3242054Z git-lfs/2.11.0 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.13.4)
2020-09-04T10:08:52.3243320Z ##[command]git init "/home/vsts/work/1/s"
2020-09-04T10:08:52.3246391Z Initialized empty Git repository in /home/vsts/work/1/s/.git/
2020-09-04T10:08:52.3247198Z ##[command]git remote add origin https://github.com/aurelian84/acudoclarisa
2020-09-04T10:08:52.3255012Z ##[command]git config gc.auto 0
2020-09-04T10:08:52.3258995Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.https://github.com/aurelian84/acudoclarisa.extraheader
2020-09-04T10:08:52.3262749Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
2020-09-04T10:08:52.3266411Z ##[command]git config http.version HTTP/1.1
2020-09-04T10:08:52.3273151Z ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
2020-09-04T10:08:53.0049121Z remote: Enumerating objects: 28, done.        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.0051479Z remote: Counting objects:   3% (1/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.0141236Z remote: Counting objects:   7% (2/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.0142482Z remote: Counting objects:  10% (3/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.0143651Z remote: Counting objects:  14% (4/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.0144643Z remote: Counting objects:  17% (5/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.0639698Z remote: Counting objects:  21% (6/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1184257Z remote: Counting objects:  25% (7/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1199865Z remote: Counting objects:  28% (8/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1201614Z remote: Counting objects:  32% (9/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1202205Z remote: Counting objects:  35% (10/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1202789Z remote: Counting objects:  39% (11/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1203346Z remote: Counting objects:  42% (12/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1203914Z remote: Counting objects:  46% (13/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1204469Z remote: Counting objects:  50% (14/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1205035Z remote: Counting objects:  53% (15/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1205595Z remote: Counting objects:  57% (16/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1206185Z remote: Counting objects:  60% (17/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1206756Z remote: Counting objects:  64% (18/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1207308Z remote: Counting objects:  67% (19/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1207872Z remote: Counting objects:  71% (20/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1208420Z remote: Counting objects:  75% (21/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1208984Z remote: Counting objects:  78% (22/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1209551Z remote: Counting objects:  82% (23/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1210134Z remote: Counting objects:  85% (24/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1210686Z remote: Counting objects:  89% (25/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1211251Z remote: Counting objects:  92% (26/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1211797Z remote: Counting objects:  96% (27/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1212361Z remote: Counting objects: 100% (28/28)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1212944Z remote: Counting objects: 100% (28/28), done.        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1213644Z remote: Compressing objects:   5% (1/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1214247Z remote: Compressing objects:  10% (2/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1214812Z remote: Compressing objects:  15% (3/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1216150Z remote: Compressing objects:  20% (4/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1216738Z remote: Compressing objects:  25% (5/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1217301Z remote: Compressing objects:  30% (6/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1217889Z remote: Compressing objects:  35% (7/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1218448Z remote: Compressing objects:  40% (8/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1219020Z remote: Compressing objects:  45% (9/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1219586Z remote: Compressing objects:  50% (10/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1220771Z remote: Compressing objects:  55% (11/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1221309Z remote: Compressing objects:  60% (12/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1221841Z remote: Compressing objects:  65% (13/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1222352Z remote: Compressing objects:  70% (14/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1222858Z remote: Compressing objects:  75% (15/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1223509Z remote: Compressing objects:  80% (16/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1224032Z remote: Compressing objects:  85% (17/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1224521Z remote: Compressing objects:  90% (18/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1225025Z remote: Compressing objects:  95% (19/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1225527Z remote: Compressing objects: 100% (20/20)        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1226052Z remote: Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.        
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1227275Z remote: Total 28 (delta 5), reused 12 (delta 1), pack-reused 0
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1227804Z From https://github.com/aurelian84/acudoclarisa
2020-09-04T10:08:53.1228477Z  * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2004470Z ##[command]git checkout --progress --force 56d939fcfba1fd33d1b2b9b38cb04505e856394b
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2007747Z Note: switching to '56d939fcfba1fd33d1b2b9b38cb04505e856394b'.
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2008136Z 
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2008623Z You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2009046Z changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2009442Z state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2009687Z 
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2009963Z If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2010890Z do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2011164Z 
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2011529Z   git switch -c <new-branch-name>
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2011726Z 
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2011941Z Or undo this operation with:
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2012135Z 
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2012448Z   git switch -
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2012595Z 
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2012893Z Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2013145Z 
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2013393Z HEAD is now at 56d939f new index.html update
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2061118Z ##[section]Finishing: Checkout aurelian84/acudoclarisa@master to s
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2091800Z ##[section]Starting: Run a one-line script
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2098681Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2099056Z Task         : Command line
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2099485Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2099852Z Version      : 2.164.2
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2100156Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2100573Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2020-09-04T10:08:53.2101028Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-04T10:08:53.6501724Z Generating script.
2020-09-04T10:08:53.6516311Z Script contents:
2020-09-04T10:08:53.6516583Z echo Hello, world!
2020-09-04T10:08:53.6517278Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2020-09-04T10:08:53.6539765Z [command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/ddcca1ed-63f3-412f-99a5-56b8b6240deb.sh
2020-09-04T10:08:53.6630129Z Hello, world!
2020-09-04T10:08:53.6638605Z 
2020-09-04T10:08:53.6702318Z ##[section]Finishing: Run a one-line script
2020-09-04T10:08:53.6728249Z ##[section]Starting: Run a multi-line script
2020-09-04T10:08:53.6735810Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-04T10:08:53.6736188Z Task         : Command line
2020-09-04T10:08:53.6736607Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2020-09-04T10:08:53.6736980Z Version      : 2.164.2
2020-09-04T10:08:53.6737286Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-09-04T10:08:53.6737697Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2020-09-04T10:08:53.6738173Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-04T10:08:53.8156675Z Generating script.
2020-09-04T10:08:53.8170866Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2020-09-04T10:08:53.8196986Z [command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/201b8759-ec27-4acf-937b-4d793793b47c.sh
2020-09-04T10:08:53.8272354Z Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
2020-09-04T10:08:53.8276006Z See https://aka.ms/yaml
2020-09-04T10:08:53.8291078Z 
2020-09-04T10:08:53.8352009Z ##[section]Finishing: Run a multi-line script
2020-09-04T10:08:53.8379815Z ##[section]Starting: Checkout aurelian84/acudoclarisa@master to s
2020-09-04T10:08:53.8384214Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-04T10:08:53.8384595Z Task         : Get sources
2020-09-04T10:08:53.8384966Z Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
2020-09-04T10:08:53.8385324Z Version      : 1.0.0
2020-09-04T10:08:53.8385561Z Author       : Microsoft
2020-09-04T10:08:53.8385956Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
2020-09-04T10:08:53.8386405Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-04T10:08:54.1968674Z Cleaning any cached credential from repository: aurelian84/acudoclarisa (GitHub)
2020-09-04T10:08:54.1978532Z ##[section]Finishing: Checkout aurelian84/acudoclarisa@master to s
2020-09-04T10:08:54.2035762Z ##[section]Starting: Finalize Job
2020-09-04T10:08:54.2068552Z Cleaning up task key
2020-09-04T10:08:54.2070128Z Start cleaning up orphan processes.
2020-09-04T10:08:54.2373252Z ##[section]Finishing: Finalize Job
2020-09-04T10:08:54.2415334Z ##[section]Finishing: Job
```

Best Regards,
Aurelian

Comment: Ccheck pipeline logs, you may not have permission

Comment: I added the release pipeline logs

Comment: Can you share your pipeline definitions? The Release output looks like you have an empty pipeline.

Comment: I  shared the pipeline definitions. I cannot share yml content of the release pipeline. First time the release pipeline was empty but now it is not and I have tried multiple tasks but neither of them upload my git content into my azure static web container

Comment: Looks like we're still missing the error your screenshot is showing in the Release pipeline. Something is preventing the upload to blob storage. Can you share those logs?

Answer (score 2):

> azure pipelines for static website hosted on azure storage blob

According to the error image you provided in release pipeline:

```
Upload to container: '$web' in storage account: ... uploading files to blob storage.' For more info
```

Obviously, this error prevents azure copy task from updating the static website.

To resolve this issue, please make sure you are using the AzCopy version to `v7.3.0` and above (Try to use the `V3` and `V4` for the azure copy task).

If you are already using the `V3` or `V4` version, please make sure the Service Principal we use in this task have access to the Storage Account. You could try to navigate to `Storage accounts`
-> `Access control` page and `Add a role assignment`(Storage Blob Data Contributor/owner role) to my Service Principal/Managed Identity:

[image]

Besides, check also your Service Connection in your Azure DevOps Project Settings for identifying that you are using the correct Resource Group.

You could check [this thread](https://gitmemory.com/issue/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/7611/612676613) for some more details.

Comment: @aurelianr, That is OK, Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: I added the role but i cannot solve the next error: 
`Upload to container: '$web' in storage account: 'acudoclarisawebv3' with blob prefix: '' failed with error: 'AzCopy.exe exited with non-zero exit code while uploading files to blob storage.' For more info please refer to https://aka.ms/azurefilecopyreadme` because the  RESPONSE Status: 403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

Comment: It seems that Az File copy need a parameter like a key in order to be authorized to copy the files

Answer (score 1):

Please read the following two blog posts, which are very detailed. If you are unclear, you can watch the video. I watched it carefully, every step of the operation is very clear, it will definitely help you.

[1. How to use Azure DevOps Pipeline and Cake to generate a static website](https://www.frankysnotes.com/2019/03/how-to-use-azure-devops-pipeline-and.html)

[2. Deploy automatically a static website into an Azure Blob storage with Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://www.frankysnotes.com/2019/03/deploy-automatically-static-website.html)

As you can see from your screenshot, many operations in the release of Azure Devops failed. Then the deployment will definitely be problematic. Hope the blog I provided can help you.

Comment: thanks . I will read and I will send you a feedback

Comment: I saw the 2. Deploy automatically a static website into an Azure Blob storage with Azure DevOps Pipeline and I observed that is deprecated the example from here do not work anymore.